# Two dimensional table index generator using Python's itertools

Tags: python, iterator, generator, sequence, python-itertools

I'd like to place items from a list at sequential indexes of a table, with the number of columns being controlled by the input. I know how to do this the "boring" way by incrementing or resetting integers at the end of each column, but I figure there is probably a more elegant way to do this with Python's `itertools` library.

Consider this list:

```
items = ["Apple", "Orange", "Pear", "Strawberry", "Banana"]
```

Here is the boring way:

```
def table_indexes(items, ncol):
    col = 0
    row = 0

    for item in items:
        yield (col, row)
        col += 1
        if col >= ncol:
            # end of row
            col = 0
            row += 1
```

This would yield indexes that place the items at the following table indexes:

```
| Apple  | Orange     |
| Pear   | Strawberry |
| Banana |            |
```

I'd like to find a function in `itertools` or elsewhere that can yield a sequence of index pairs where one index in each pair cycles through a sequence of numbers repeatedly (column numbers), and the other index increases by 1 every time the first cycle repeats? Like so:

```
def table_indexes(items, ncol):
    cols = ... # e.g. itertools.cycle(range(ncol))
    rows = ... # needs to be an iterator yielding sequences of [i]*ncol where i is the current row index
    yield zip(cols, rows):
```

Can the solution be extended to N dimensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you can use [repeat](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat).

```
from itertools import chain, repeat

def table_indexes(items, ncol):
    cols = chain.from_iterable(repeat(range(ncol), len(items)//ncol + 1))
    for x, (col, item) in enumerate(zip(cols, items)):
    yield x//ncol, col, item

items = ["Apple", "Orange", "Pear", "Strawberry", "Banana"]
list(table_indexes(items, 3))
```

output:

```
[(0, 0, 'Apple'),
 (0, 1, 'Orange'),
 (0, 2, 'Pear'),
 (1, 0, 'Strawberry'),
 (1, 1, 'Banana')]
```

more details, the repeat gives us an list of columns

`repeat(range(ncol), len(items)//ncol + 1)` --> `[[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]]`

and while we loop through the enumeration of the items, the construction `x // ncol` gives us the number of the row.

Comment: Looks good! I wonder if such a method could be included in Python's `itertools` standard library. It's probably a niche use case, but I figure this problem will crop up in lots of different applications.

Comment: need to write to the python core developers)